# POSTFIX : 'loops back to myself'

Tags: postfix

I have been stuck with this status for the past 3 days, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have this docker-mailserver, that can send mails to public SMTP hosts (outlook, gmail ..) but not to itself. When trying to send from a@newproject.org to b@newproject.org, I get the following log :

```
May 18 21:48:55 mail postfix/smtp[9268]: 34C559BE: to=<arthur@newproject.org>, relay=none, delay=0.21, delays=0.02/0/0.18/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for newproject.org loops back to myself)
```

here is the output of `postconf -n`

```
alias_database = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf
alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
compatibility_level = 2
content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
disable_vrfy_command = yes
dkim_milter = inet:localhost:8891
dmarc_milter = inet:localhost:8893
inet_interfaces = allinet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = newproject.org
myhostname = mail.newproject.org
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64 172.20.0.30/32
non_smtpd_milters = $dkim_milterpolicyd-spf_time_limit = 3600postscreen_bare_newline_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_action = enforce
postscreen_dnsbl_sites = zen.spamhaus.org*3 bl.mailspike.net b.barracudacentral.org*2 bl.spameatingmonkey.net bl.spamcop.net dnsbl.sorbs.net psbl.surriel.com list.dnswl.org=127.0.[0..255].0*-2 list.dnswl.org=127.0.[0..255].1*-3 list.dnswl.org=127.0.[0..255].[2..3]*-4
postscreen_dnsbl_threshold = 3
postscreen_dnsbl_whitelist_threshold = -1
postscreen_greet_action = enforce
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
smtp_header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/maps/sender_header_filter.pcre
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = texthash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit
smtpd_milters = $dkim_milter,$dmarc_milter
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_dh1024_param_file = /etc/postfix/dhparams.pem
smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = aNULL, LOW, EXP, MEDIUM, ADH, AECDH, MD5, DSS, ECDSA, CAMELLIA128, 3DES, CAMELLIA256, RSA+AES, eNULL
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3,!TLSv1,!TLSv1.1
smtpd_tls_security_level = none
smtpd_use_tls = no
tls_high_cipherlist = ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
tls_ssl_options = NO_COMPRESSION
virtual_alias_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-aliases.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-groups.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mail.newproject.org, /etc/postfix/vhost, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-users.cf
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/run/dovecot/lmtp
```

I have a MX record type for `mail.newproject.org` that points to the container (internal IP address).

What have I done that could cause the loop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I had been confused with the domain name VS hostname

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = mail.newproject.org, /etc/postfix/vhost, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-domains.cf
```

Replacing it with

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = newproject.org, /etc/postfix/vhost, ldap:/etc/postfix/ldap-domains.cf
```

Fixed the problem